# Condition based on unique column values

Tags: r

I want to print different messages if the values in a column are unique or not unique:

```
df <- data.frame (test  = c(1,1,1,2,2),
                  number = c(3,7,5,1,6)
)

if(unique(df$test)){
  print("unique")
  
  } else {
    print("not unique")
    }
```

It should print `not unique` since test does not have unique numbers. I get this warning message:

```
[1] "unique"
Warning message:
In if (unique(df$test)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unique(df$test)` returns the vector of unique values and not a logical vector.  We need a logical vector of `length` 1 in `if` and that can be done by wrapping with `length` and check if the length is the same as the number of elements (`length(df$test)` or number of row in this case as it is a data.frame `nrow(df)`)

```
 if(length(unique(df$test)) == nrow(df)){
  print("unique")
  } else {
    print("not unique")
    }
```